# Arduino Quadcopter using bluetooth shield and android phone

Tags: arduino, quadcopter

I need help on how to go about building a quadcopter software from scratch with the available tools I have with me. I don't have a transmitter radio therefore the only way I can do remote control is using an android phone with the itead studio bluetooth shield that I was recently given.
How can I use the existing open source software, i.e aeroquad or arducopter. The following are parts that I have:-

1. Arduino Uno
2. Bluetooth shield
3. Four brushless motors
4. Q450 frame Four
5. ESC Turnigy
6. MPU6050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need to test the communication range. Make a test app to talk between the phone and arduino/bluetooth shield and then walk around to see how far away they can still communicate. If it's not far enough you can't do much else and need to find a different communication solution.

After that, you will need to modify the source code from the open source projects you referenced as I don't believe they use the same setup as you. First, you will need to modify/replace the communication logic to use your bluetooth. Second, you won't be able to do autonomous flight with those sensors so you will need to strip out anything related to that from the code.

Finally, you just need to define your own protocol for sending movement commands from the phone to the bluetooth shield.